# Sending proactive message with image

Tags: botframework

I am using botframework with the Node API and was wondering how can I send a proactive message with a HeroCard attachment that has an image thumbnail.

My main issue is that I can't create a CardImage without having a session.

```
app.get("/api/send_notification", (req, res) => {
    let address = req.body.adr;
    let msg = new builder.Message().address(address).text("some text");

    let card = new builder.HeroCard()
            .title("title")
            .text("hero card text");

// .images([builder.CardImage.create(session, imgURL)]);
// There is no session when sending a proactive message;

    msg.addAttachment(card);
    bot.send(msg);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using

```
let img = [{url: imgURL}];
let card = new builder.HeroCard()
        .title("title")
        .text("hero card text")
        .images(img);
```

`img` must be an **array**